# Trying to get numeric value of uppercase & lowercase in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to answer the question that asks for user input in entering three alphabetical letters (eg. `a=1`, `b=2`,… `A=101`, `B=102`, etc) and then the total sum.

So far I can only get the first lowercase user input working correctly?

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I don’t think there’d be any principal difference in how I’d handle uppercase and lowercase letters, so if you show us the code that is working for a lowercase letter, I’m certain that we can help you how to adopt it for uppercase and for more than one letter. [I downvoted because lacking an MCVE makes it hard to answer](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the letters from their ascii value

```
Scanner scnObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a word");
        String input1 = scnObj.nextLine();
        char[] arr=input1.toCharArray(); 
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            int ascii=(int)arr[i];
            if(ascii>=97&&ascii<=122)
            { // 
                total=total+ascii-96; //ascii are set values, a-z = 97-122 etc
            } 
            else if(ascii>=65&&ascii<=90)
            {
                total=total+ascii+36;  //This will convert A-Z values to 101 etc values
            }
            else if(ascii>=48&&ascii<=57)
            {
                total=total+ascii-48;  //value of the digit to be worth itself
            }
            else
            {
                total=total+0;  //special character to be worth 0
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. Generally we should not give any good answer to such a hopelessly poor question (sorry I’m frank), and not answer questions that look like homework with full code. We’re doing no one any favour that way, and I fear that we risk attracting more hopelessly poor questions. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @OleV.V. you are right my apologies!